# IF statement for surplus

Tags: excel

Calculate the cash available to retire debt for each of the six months. There is cash available to retire debt if there is a cash surplus at the end of a month (shortfall/surplus cash > 0). Therefore cash available to retire debt is equal to any cash surplus at the end of a month. If there is not a surplus, cash available to retire debt is 0.

Trying to solve this for my class what i have so far is

```
=d28,if>0
```

Please help me to know what to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the IF function is

> IF(logical_test, value_if_true, [value_if_false])

So in your case the logical test is

> D28>0

If that is true then you want to display the value of D28 else 0 so your formula will be

`=IF(D28>0,D28,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at this would be to simply take the `MAX` of zero and the value in D28.

```
=MAX(D28, 0)
```

Any positive number in D28 will return that positive number. Any negative number in D28 will return zero.